# Обработка числовой последовательности

Tags: python, файловая-система, числовые-последовательности

Есть задание:

> В файле содержится последовательность из 10 000 целых положительных чисел. Каждое число не превышает 10 000. Определите и запишите в ответе сначала количество пар элементов последовательности, у которых сумма элементов кратна 7, затем максимальную из сумм элементов таких пар. В данной задаче под парой подразумевается два различных элемента последовательности. Порядок элементов в паре не важен.

[Файл](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1erCwUHZk-RJvCs8GkYO1tcChivHTY-lz/view?usp=sharing)

Мой код:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    s = [int(x) for x in f]
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
        for j in range(1, len(s)):
            if (s[i] + s[j]) % 7 == 0:
                r.append(s[i] + s[j])
    print(len(r), max(r))
```

Ответ должен быть таким: **7142586 19992** (1 - количество пар, кратных 7; 2 - максимальная возможная сумма)

Мой код в результате выдаёт **14283730 19992**. Не могу понять, почему отличается количество  пар

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы делаете циклы с `i` и `j` не зависящими друг от друга, от чего легко могут быть случаи, когда одна и та же пара чисел будет засчитана дважды. Например, при `i = 2` и `j = 3` программе ничего не мешает взять `i = 3` и `j = 2` и обработать её, хотя по идее пара чисел с данными индексами будет эквивалентна предыдущей паре.

Для решения достаточно начинать второй цикл не с `1`, а с `i + 1` — так не будет повторяющихся пар, и все пары чисел будут обработаны ровно единожды.

```py
with open('file.txt') as f:
    s = [int(x) for x in f]
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(s)): # <----
            if (s[i] + s[j]) % 7 == 0:
                r.append(s[i] + s[j])
    print(len(r), max(r))
```

Comment: Спасибо дружище

Comment: Отдельно стоит добавить что вообще-то нет нужды хранить все суммы, достаточно хранить количество и текущий максимум.